# POM.xml user-defined parameters not recognized - Maven mojo

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, pom.xml, mojo

I am trying to write a maven plugin to execute a copy I feed in the mojo. Its like a wrapper around the given command(have plans to extend it to take any command other than copy). The user parameters like source directory and destination directory will come from POM. I am using  POM property to define my parameters and using @Parameter annotation in mojo to recognize those. But my pom doesnt recognize the parameters. It prints null when I log it from my mojo.

I'm executing the plugin as a module from the parent POM.

Below is my pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.training.exec</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-mojo-maventest</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>  <!--try removing this to see what happens-->
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.training.exec</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-plugin-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <name>Sample Mojo Plugin</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.training.exec</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-mojo-maven</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>executeCmd</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <srcDir>C:\Users\ashw8450\Desktop\DummySrc</srcDir>
                            <destDir>C:\Users\ashw8450\Desktop\DummyDest</destDir>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Below is my mojo:

```
package com.training.exec;

import org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractMojo;
import org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException;
import org.apache.maven.plugins.annotations.Mojo;
import org.apache.maven.plugins.annotations.Parameter;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * @goal executeCmd
 *
 * @phase compile
 */

@Mojo(name = "execute")

public class execMojo extends AbstractMojo{

    @Parameter
    private String srcDir;

    @Parameter
    private String destDir;

    public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException
    {
        getLog().info( "Hello, world!!!!." + srcDir+" to ");
    }
}
```

I tried to take them as String, tried to take as File. Both didn't work. The mvn compile phase runs successfully. but prints null for the parameters. I tried executing it with breakpoints in mojo using debug mode..I'm having some issues with getting accustomed to intelliJ but I think debug mode will show the null too and is not of much use here.. Any guidance is appreciated. Thanks!

@ShireResident I've pasted the parent pom?:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.training.exec</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-plugin-parent</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <name>Mojo plugin parent</name>
      <modules>
        <module>execCmd</module>
      </modules>
```

Comment: Could you paste the mojo's pom?

Answer (score 3):

By giving a field the annotation @Parameter you say that this field can be used within the configuration-block of the plugin. By setting the @Parameter(property="myplugin.myfield") you expose it and now you can set from commandline or a properties-value in the pom.xml
Wise lesson: the name or alias of the field is NOT the same as the name of the property: they are handled differently.

Comment: I tried this but still it couldn't recognize the parameter. Please note that I have defined the parameters in <configuration> tag of POM.  I also included maven-plugin-plugin  - default-descriptor..

Comment: /**
     * @goal executeCmd
     *
     * @phase compile
     */
     @Mojo(name = "execute")

You're mixing to technics: annotations and doclet tags. You must choose 1, preferrably the annotation.
Try `@Mojo(name = "executeCmd", defaultPhase="compile")